# What's the best way to upstream and downstream media in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api

Recently I came across a requirement to define the best strategy to upload and download media for Mobile App. Website data is managed under Sitecore CMS currently.

At first glance, below thoughts came in my mind. I want your help and suggestion to find the best approach, especially if you have worked on such a requirement.

1) Create API to send and receive text/html data from Sitecore CMS to Mobile and vice versa

2) Create API to send and receive Image/Video data from Sitecore CMS to Mobile and vice versa.

If so, what is the best way to upload video programmatically in Sitecore? OR Would be good to upload a video on any streaming provider (e.g YouTube or Brightcove) and store video link in Sitecore?

OR

3) Write some API to receive Image/Video data from DAM to Mobile and vice versa. Has anyone done such API implementation to interact with DAM?

Which one approaches you recommend?

The client is more inclined towards DAM approach. What would you suggest for DAM in Sitecore? Which one would be the best DAM to upload images/video programmatically from Mobile App?

Thank you,
Nilesh

Comment: How to review the data?, virus scan, expected size?, amount of data?.. or option 4) store the data in Azure blob storage with a serverless upload function.